# MySQL Clustered vs Non Clustered Index Performance

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, clustered-index, non-clustered-index

I'm running a couple tests on MySQL Clustered vs Non Clustered indexes where I have a table `100gb_table` which contains ~60 million rows:

```
100gb_table schema:
CREATE TABLE 100gb_table (
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    c1 int,
    c2 text,
    c3 text,
    c4 blob NOT NULL,
    c5 text,
    c6 text,
    ts timestamp NOT NULL default(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
);
```

and I'm executing a query that only reads the clustered index:

```
SELECT id FROM 100gb_table ORDER BY id;
```

I'm seeing that it takes almost an **~55 min** for this query to complete which is strangely slow. I modified the table by adding another index on top of the Primary Key column and ran the following query which forces the non-clustered index to be used:

```
SELECT id FROM 100gb_table USE INDEX (non_clustered_key) ORDER BY id;
```

This finished in **<10 minutes**, much faster than reading with the clustered index. Why is there such a large discrepancy between these two? My understanding is that both indexes store the index column's values in a tree structure, except the clustered index contains table data in the leaf nodes so I would expect both queries to be similarly performant. Could the BLOB column possibly be distorting the clustered index structure?

Comment: Run explain on both selects and share the results. Please also share the exact list of fields in the secondary index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer comes in how the data is laid out.

The `PRIMARY KEY` is "clustered" with the data; that is, the data is order ed by the PK in a B+Tree structure.  To read all of the `ids`, the entire BTree must be read.

Any secondary index is also in a B+Tree structure, but it contains (1) the columns of the index, and (2) any other columns in the PK.

In your example (with lots of [presumably] bulky columns), the data BTree is a lot bigger than the secondary index (on just `id`).  Either test probably required reading all the relevant blocks from the disk.

A side note...  This is not as bad as it could be.  There is a limit of about 8KB on how big a row can be.  `TEXT` and `BLOB` columns, when short enough, are included in that 8KB.  But when one is bulky, it is put in another place, leaving behind a 'pointer' to the text/blob.  Hence, the main part of the data BTree is smaller than it might be if all the text/blob data were included directly.

Since `SELECT id FROM tbl` is a mostly unnecessary query, the design of InnoDB does not worry about the inefficiency you discovered.

Tack on `ORDER BY` or `WHERE`, etc, and there are many different optimizations that could into play.  You might even find that `INDEX(c1)` will let your query run in not much more than 10 minutes.  (I think I have given you all the clues for 'why'.)

Also, if you had done `SELECT * FROM tbl`, it might have taken much longer than 55 minutes.  This is because of having extra [random] fetches to get the texts/blobs from the "off-record" storage.  And from the network time to shovel far more data.

Comment: So if I want to read only the values in the index column, it's generally better to use a secondary index?

Comment: @vrare - Yes.  However, fetching only `ids` is uncommon; usually it is followed by some other `SELECT`.  The two would be better executed via a single `JOIN`.